# Geolocation in Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, database, geolocation, core-location

I am a newbee to Iphone App Development and struggling with my first application.

I have a database with few address in it. All I have to do is get the current location and pick the closest three address from the database and of-course have to show the current location and the selected three nearest address on a map with directions on them.

I had a look at the Xcode frameworks LocateMe, CurrentAddress and MKReverseGeocoder Class Reference.

But then not sure how to co-ordinate this all together in an orderly manner.

Any suggestions/assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear Xcode does not have any frameworks. Cocoa Touch does. Also, `LocateMe` and `CurrentAddress` are just sample projects that make use of CoreLocation and MapKit frameworks.

Comment: @Eimantas : Oh that makes more sense now.. Thank you.. Could you possibly assist me with any other suggestions pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide lat/lon with your addresses in your database, so do the geocoding of the addresses before.

You have a location manager (CLLocationManager) which takes care of your current position, and with each location (CLLocation) you can calculate the distance (distanceFormLocation:). Now you only need to sort your database with this and pick the first three items.

Hmm?

Comment: Hey.. I managed to get the current location details and to calculate the distance from location method. however I have hard coded the values now. I am new to objective C and struggling with Database manipulation. I need to calculate the distance for every address in the database till I get the closest three locations (ie lowest three distance values).Tried a couple of tutorials online. But thn No Luck.. Can somebody pls advice on this or point few tutorials/ Sample Code related to this.